# jQuery loop through table rows and select certain inputs

Tags: jquery, rows

I have a table. Rows can be added/removed dynamically. The td's have form inputs in them. How do i loop through the rows and reference the current rows inputs? The names of the form inputs are created on the fly.

If you look at the jsfiddle, i'm trying to update the the second input based on the first and third inputs. Then, i need to set the next row's first input to that newly calculated value.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GmgAe/4/)

Answer (score 0):

you may target the next row by calling

```
var nextRow = $(this).next();
```

but your code has so many bugs, that finding the next row is your slightest problem.

Examples:

```
//nth-child is not zero based
var start = $("td:nth-child(0) input", this).val();

//there is no such function (maybe you extended Date, then it would be ok)
Date.parse(start,"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

and `actualDate` should be `startDate`, right?